# Number of ways to pick elements such mutual ordering remains maintained?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The number of ways to pick elements from two sets such that mutual ordering remains intact of both the sets.

```
For example:
Set 1:(a,b)
Set2:(c,d)
What I mean is a should come before b in any order you pick similarly c before d.
Number of ways is 6
{abcd,acdb,acbd,cabd,cadb,cdab}
```

Comment: Hint: Stars_and_bars.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks!!

Comment: @bof Suppose that the (ordered) sets have $n$ and $m$ elements. Then to be found is the number of sums $k_1+\cdots+k_{n+1}=m$ where the $k_i$ are nonnegative integers. First place the elements of the set having $n$ elements on a row. Then place elements of the other set in the gaps and on LHS and RHS.

Comment: @bof I must agree it is more trouble :-). It was the first thing that came to mind and was projected immediately as a hint. Fortunately it was well-received by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if the first ordered set has $m$ elements and the second $n$, then every such order is found by having $n+m$ places reserved and picking the $m$ places where the elements of the first set are going to go (in order). The remaining places get the second set elements (also in order).

Picking $m$ places from $n+m$ can be done in $\binom{n+m}{m}$ ways. Note that we could also pick the places for set $2$ first too, but this gives the same result as $\binom{n+m}{n} = \binom{n+m}{m}$.

In your case $n=m=2$ and indeed $\binom{4}{2} = \frac{4!}{2! 2!} = \frac{24}{4}=6$.